# SQL Server 2016 Restore Failure on DB Using Clustered Shared Volumes (Error 7627)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2016, restore, full-text-search

We are new to using clustered shared volumes and SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition.

When restoring SQL Server 2005 databases with full text search catalogs onto our new 2016 instance, we get the following SQL Server error:

> Msg 7627, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot create the full-text catalog in the directory `C:\ClusterStorage\Volume2\SQLData\LogBook` for the clustered server. Only directories on a disk in the cluster group of the server can be used.

We have restored this same database to a SQL Server 2016 without issue using:

```
USE [master];
RESTORE DATABASE [MYDATABASE]
FROM DISK = N'\\BACKUPSERVER\BACKUPS\DATABASE\Database_backup_201805070600.bak'
WITH FILE = 1,
     MOVE N'DatabaseData'
     TO N'C:\ClusterStorage\Volume2\SQLData\Database.mdf',
     MOVE N'DatabaseLog'
     TO N'C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\SQLTranLogs\Database_log.ldf',
     MOVE N'sysft_LogBook'
     TO N'C:\ClusterStorage\Volume2\SQLData\LogBook',
     NOUNLOAD,
     REPLACE,
     STATS = 5;
```

Have any of you ran into this using clustered shared volume instead of just a plain volume?

Here are some shots of the setup on the cluster using CSVs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Using the old method on shared volumes our dependencies looked like this example:

[image]

Now using clustered shared volumes which are using SMB they look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Windows Failover Cluster 2016, you need to ensure all storage (except for node-local-tempdb) is configured as a dependent resource in the SQL Server cluster role.

In the example below, you can see this cluster has two disks, Disk_F and Disk_G; those are the only places where SQL Server will allow us to create data and log files for SQL Server.

[image]

When restoring a SQL Server 2005 database that has a full text catalog, you likely need to specify the location of the full-text catalog files, otherwise SQL Server will attempt to put them in the default location, which may not be on a cluster shared volume.  Use `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '\path\to\backup';` to determine the files that exist in the backup.  Ensure your restore statement has a `MOVE` clause for each file in the backup.

As a workaround, you might try restoring the SQL Server 2005 full-text-search-enabled database onto a non-clustered SQL Server 2016 instance, then take a backup of the database from the 2016 instance to restore onto the clustered 2016 instance.  I'm thinking it's possible there is a bug in the restore process for old full-text-enabled databases onto modern clustered instances.